# Thinking Sphinx hangs while indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm using Thinking Sphinx to index a single table with 43,000 records. When I try to index it, the process runs very slowly and freezes after 36,000.

I assumed that there was some problem with the data and tried to discover which index caused the problem. After removing all but 11 indexes, I still consistently see the error. But here's the rub: no single index appears to be the culprit. If I remove any one of the last 11, the process finishes without freezing. If I add it back, the problem comes back. (Though I have noticed that when I remove one of these indexes, the process still slows down a lot at 39,000.)

So now I'm stumped. I have plenty of ram and disk space, so that's not the issue. I set sql_range_step to 15000 and mem_limit to 2047M. Nothing helps.

Here is my pared-down list of indexes:

```
  define_index do
    indexes :email
    has :id, :as => :code
    has :premium_school_id
    has :current_employer_account_id
    has :years_experience_id
    has :user_status_id
    has practice_areas(:id), :as => :practice_area_ids
    has languages(:id), :as => :language_ids
    has preferred_employer_types(:id), :as => :preferred_employer_type_ids
    has geographical_regions(:id), :as => :geographical_region_ids
    has workflow_events(:id), :as => :workflow_event_ids
  end
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Pat Allan recently answered a similar question for me, might be worth reading up on this thread to see if it helps.

Basically it was to do with a lot of joins from has_and_belongs_to_many relations and the way Thinking Sphinx generates the resulting SQL.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/thinking-sphinx/CBdWy-RivaU/tBRlLci83IkJ